# Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format

Tags: java, maven

Team,

Getting the following error on my pom file.  Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format.  I went thru the URL provided but still getting the error. MVN version 3.2.1,Java version: 1.7.0_51 any help would be appreciated

POM looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.organization.dramer</groupId>
<artifactId>sTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>sTest</name>
<description>test automation framework created using Java, testNG,
selenium</description>


  <properties>
  <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
  <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>

      </dependencies>

  <build>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile)</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>    
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>




  </build>




</project>
```

Comment: What command are you running? What does your `pom.xml` look like?

Comment: mvn clean, then mvn build

Comment: `build` is not a standard phase for maven. Did you mean to use `mvn compile` (builds/compiles the project) or `mvn test` (compiles and runs all unit tests)?

Comment: mvn compile throws all kinds of errors For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Answer (score 31):

Maven doesn't have `build` target (*phase* in Maven lingo), what you probably want is either `compile`, `test` or `install` depending what you want to achieve.

Please read through [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) to learn more about how Maven lifecycle works and what each step does.

Comment: mvn test works well but defining with cucumber tags fails

Answer (score 3):

maven haven't any `build` target, it means if you are run `mvn build` command.
this command doesn't exist in maven lifecycle.

- you have to run `mvn package` for run the project
- `mvn compile` for compile
- `mvn test` for test
- `mvn install` for install
- `mvn clean build` -run the build phases of the default lifecycle and for each build phase all the plugin goals they contain are executed.